# Get all records from current day based on datetime in different time zone

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, timezone-offset

I need to select all records for the current day in CST, however the timestamp fields in the table are all in GMT/UTC.

The server's timezone is GMT.

Getting all records for the current day in GMT is very fast about 0.031 seconds fetch according to MySQL workbench, and for the view with the -6 added it takes about 40 seconds.

I've tried a few

```sql
CAST(CONVERT_TZ(`CallLog`.`gmtDateTime`, '+00:00', '-06:00') AS DATE) = CAST(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00') AS DATE)
```

`gmtDateTime` is a Timestamp, so might be able to do something with that?

I believe the reason it is slow is the left hand expression is calculated for every record in the table and can't be cached (However this is a guess, not super familiar with the internals of MySQL)

The obvious solution would be to add the CST time as a column and filter based on that, but unfortunately that isn't an option as we don't have any control over the software that populates the table, and would rather not modify the schema of the table itself.

Comment: it make3s no sense convert the timezone on  both sides with the same value, when the time is equal for the new time zone it is also true for the original timezone

Comment: @nbk The value on both sides isnt the same value? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: your new time zone on both sides is + 06:00, the change on both sides the same, so no need to change the tomezone

Comment: Yes but if I were to not to change the timezone, it would select records between 00:00 to 23:59 in GMT. Instead it needs to be between 6:00 GMT to 5:59 GMT the next day

Comment: @user1191247 TIMESTAMP, my bad

Comment: And the session time zone?

Comment: GMT. I thought of trying to set the time_zone variable, but you can't do anything other then SELECT in a view.

Comment: @gsck He is trying to let you know that you are converting timezone on both sides of the comparison.  NOW() will return the current date in the timezone based on server setting, which is probably CST but you can find out. If your server timezone is in fact CST then you don't need to convert timezone for the side that uses NOW() but if it's -6 you don't need to convert at all. hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @LarryBeasley The server time zone is in GMT, I probably should've clarified that in the question. Both the field and server are GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely as you pointed out it has to convert your gmtDateTime for each row and do a full table scan.

Remove the conversion of `gmtDateTime` and select using a upper and lower bound timestamp based on `NOW()`. Your `WHERE` condition would then look something like this:

```
gmtDateTime BETWEEN
  CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00'), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), '-06:00', '+00:00') AND
  CONVERT_TZ(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00'), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'), '-06:00', '+00:00');
```

Comment: This worked a charm. Thanks! Just hope I never have to deal with timezones ever again

Comment: You're welcome! It does get easier if you have control over the timestamp insertion so you can store all of them in UTC and only convert to other timezones when needed in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

If the current date/time is `2023-10-23 04:00:00 UTC` and we want all records for current CST day, we need to convert current date/time to CST to get the current date in CST (`2023-10-22`), and then convert back to UTC:

```sql
WHERE gmtDateTime >= CONVERT_TZ(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00')), '-06:00', '+00:00')
  AND gmtDateTime <  CONVERT_TZ(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '+00:00', '-06:00')), '-06:00', '+00:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

For `2023-10-23 04:00:00 UTC` this evaluates to:

```sql
WHERE gmtDateTime >= '2023-10-22 06:00:00'
  AND gmtDateTime <  '2023-10-23 06:00:00'
```

For `2023-10-23 12:39:27 UTC` this evaluates to:

```sql
WHERE gmtDateTime >= '2023-10-23 06:00:00'
  AND gmtDateTime <  '2023-10-24 06:00:00'
```